# Как послать текст из label одного контроллера в label другого контроллера в JavaFX?

Tags: java, javafx, scene-builder

Пишу программу с JavaFX и Scene Builder

Имеется главный класс Main который запускает программу и открывает главное окно контроллера (Controller).

```
public class Main extends Application {


  public static void main(String[] args) {
    launch(args);
  }

  @Override
  public void start(Stage primaryStage) throws Exception {
    try {

      Parent root = FXMLLoader.load(getClass().getResource("/card/card.fxml"));
      Scene scene = new Scene(root, 1600, 600);
      primaryStage.setScene(scene);
      scene.getStylesheets().add(getClass().getResource("style.css").toExternalForm());
      primaryStage.initStyle(StageStyle.UNDECORATED);
      primaryStage.setMaximized(true);
      primaryStage.setResizable(true);


      primaryStage.getIcons().add(new Image("card/resources/logo-icon.png"));
      primaryStage.show();

        //adding resize and drag primary stage
        ResizeHelper.addResizeListener(primaryStage);



      //assign ALT+ENTER to maximize window
      final KeyCombination kb = new KeyCodeCombination(KeyCode.ENTER, KeyCombination.CONTROL_DOWN);
      scene.addEventHandler(KeyEvent.KEY_PRESSED, new EventHandler<KeyEvent>() {
        @Override
        public void handle(KeyEvent event) {
          if (kb.match(event)) {
            primaryStage.setMaximized(!primaryStage.isMaximized());
            primaryStage.setResizable(true);

          }
        }
      });

    } catch (Exception e) {
      e.printStackTrace();
    }

  }

}
```

В главном окне есть label и  также  button, при нажатии на который появляется  окно с другим контроллером(FontController)

```
@FXML private Button btnFont;
@FXML  private Label category1
@FXML
  void changeFont(ActionEvent event) {
    try {
      FXMLLoader fxmlLoader = new FXMLLoader(getClass().getResource("font.fxml"));
      Parent rootFont = (Parent) fxmlLoader.load();
      Stage stage = new Stage();
      stage.setTitle("Select Font");
      stage.setScene(new Scene(rootFont));
      stage.show();    

    } catch (Exception e) {
      System.out.println("can't load new window");
    }

  }
```

В контроллере FontController есть лейбл и кнопка OK

```
@FXML  private Label fontLabel;
@FXML  private Button btnFontOk;
```

Подскажите пожалуйста, как сделать,чтобы при нажатии на кнопку ОК, текст из лейбла этого контроллера отправлялся на Controller и отобразился в label?

[image: Controller]

[image: FontController]

**РЕДАКЦИЯ:**

@boneferz я вставил этот код, но setController не распознается

[image: setController]

Comment: у вас controller имеет тип FontController? проверьте его на null перед доступом к его методам

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**РЕШЕНИЕ НАЙДЕНО:**

Правда приходится создавать много геттеров и сеттеров для каждого компонента в моей программе с которым я хочу манипулировать из других окон

В папке c проектом  я создал класс Context, он нужен для того,чтобы контроллеры общались между собой через него. В этом классе можно разместить сколько угодно необходимых контроллеров

```
package card;


public class Context {
  private final static Context instance = new Context();
  public static Context getInstance() {
    return instance;
  }

  private Controller controller;
  public void setController(Controller controller) {
    this.controller=controller;
  }

  public Controller getController() {
    return controller;
  }

  private FontController fontController;
  public void setFontController(FontController fontController) {
    this.fontController=fontController;
  }

  public FontController getFontController() {
    return fontController;
  }
}
```

Класс **Controller:**

Здесь я создал геттеры и сеттеры для лейбла, который будет меняться из другого контроллера (ALT + INSERT в IDEA)

```
public Label getCategory1() {
    return category1;
  }

  public void setCategory1(Label category1) {
    this.category1 = category1;
  }
```

чтобы получить методы и переменные FontController через класс Context, я применил код:

```
//getting FontController through Context Class
  FontController fontCont = Context.getInstance().getFontController();
```

регистрирую Controller в классе Context в методе initialize();

```
@FXML
  public void initialize(URL location, ResourceBundle resources) {

    //register Controller in  Context Class
    Context.getInstance().setController(this);

  }
```

Класс **FontController:**

чтобы получить методы и переменные Controller через класс Context, использую следующий код:

```
//getting Controller variables and methods through Context class
  Controller cont = Context.getInstance().getController();
```

также регистрирую контроллер FontController в методе initialize(); в классе Context:

```
@Override
  public void initialize(URL location, ResourceBundle resources) {

    //register FontController in  Context Class
    Context.getInstance().setFontController(this);
}
```

когда кликаю на кнопку "ОК" вызывается метод, который посылает текст и цвет текста из лейбла FontController в Controller

```
@FXML
  void applyFont(ActionEvent event) {
    cont.getCategory1().setText(fontLabel.getText());
    cont.getCategory1().setTextFill(fontLabel.getTextFill());
  }
```

**МИНУСЫ:** создание геттеров и сеттеров полей, которыми необходимо манипулировать из других контроллеров для каждого контроллера. Получается много строк кода для геттеров и сеттеров ( в моем случае)

**ПЛЮСЫ:** все контроллеры инициализируются  в одном классе

Comment: Можно поинтересоваться, где нашли такое решение?

Comment: Не могу вспомнить, на каком форуме увидел это решение, но после того как реализовал это, нашёл ещё одно похожее: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=5GsdaZWDcdY&t=507s

Comment: чего спрашиваю, я у себя в проекте точно так же сделал, вот буквально недавно. но сомневался, правильно ли это. вот, даже вопрос об данной  реализации  задал - https://ru.stackoverflow.com/q/926037/296437 вообщем теперь не сомневаюсь)

Comment: @boneferz я так понимаю есть несколько вариантов как организовать взаимодействие между контроллерами, вопрос только в том, как вот эта модель сработает если например будет контроллеров не 2, а намного больше, будет ли это оптимизированным решением, или же будет все тормозить, остается только проверять)

Comment: главное работает, и нет никаких проблем. я просто не вижу другого варианта реализации, кроме данного способа. мне он кажется самым верным на сегодня

Answer (score 0):

```
label.getText() // получить значение содержащегося текста  в label
label.setText(String text) // установить текст в label
```

Как передать в другой контроллер? У вас ложна быть ссылка на него, и доступ к его `label`

> как сделать ссылку на него и доступ к label?

```
public class Main {

    public void start(Stage primaryStage) throws Exception{
        FXMLLoader UIview = new FXMLLoader(getClass().getResource("sample.fxml"));
        Parent root = UIview.load();

        MainController view = UIview.getController(); 
        // можно юзать эту ссылку на класс главного контроллера если нужно 
    }
}

class MainController {
    @FXML public Button btnFont;
    @FXML public Label category1;

    Controller controller;

    @FXML
    void changeFont(ActionEvent event) {
        FXMLLoader fxmlLoader = new FXMLLoader(getClass().getResource("font.fxml"));
        Parent rootFont = fxmlLoader.load();
        controller = fxmlLoader.getController();

        controller.setMainController(this); // тут передать ссылку на главный контроллер (this)
    }
}

class FontController  {
    @FXML private Label fontLabel;
    @FXML private Button btnFontOk;

    MainController mainController; // тут сохранить ссылку на главный контроллер 

    void setMainController(MainController _mainController) { // тут принять ссылку 
        this.mainController = _mainController;

        mainController.category1.setText("text"); // обращаться к елементам главного контроллера 
    }

}
```

Comment: а как сделать ссылку на него и доступ к label?

Comment: дописал как добавить ссылку, попробуйте так, должно работать!

Answer (score 0):

Можно так же использовать ***связывание*** данных.

*Однонаправленное* связывание (при изменении текста *label1* будет меняться  текст *label2*) :

```
Label label1 = new Label();
Label label2 = new Label();

label2.textProperty().bind(label1.textProperty()); // текст label2 зависит от текста label1
```

Либо *двунаправленное* связывание (при изменении текста *label1* будет меняться  текст *label2* и наоборот: при изменении текста *label2* будет меняться  текст *label1*):

```
label2.textProperty().bindBidirectional(label1.textProperty());
```

Для данного примера дополню класс FontController :

```
class FontController  {
    @FXML private Label fontLabel;
    @FXML private Button btnFontOk;

    MainController mainController; // тут сохранить ссылку на главный контроллер 

    void setMainController(MainController _mainController) { // тут принять ссылку 
        this.mainController = _mainController;

        mainController.category1.textProperty().bind(fontLabel.textProperty()); // связать текст
    }

}
```

Comment: Вопрос был про связывание лейблов *КОНТРОЛЛЕРОВ* , а не лейблов внутри одного контроллера