# ООП. Взаимосвязь объектов в программе вне контекста их иерархии

Tags: ооп, шаблоны-проектирования, шаблоны

*(На всякий случай, что бы не было недопониманий: это не про наследование, а про создание объектов)*

При обычной иерархия классов "родитель - дочерние объекты", родитель знает все о ребенке и может с ним полностью взаимодействовать. Но что делать когда дети должны знать о друг друге и взаимодействовать между собой?

> Как правильно это реализовать?

Я это реализую следующим образом - для этого использую отдельный класс, допустим `GlobalData`, в него передаю ссылку на используемый объект, пусть будет `objA`. И в другом объекте `objB` получаю доступ к нужному методу первого объекта

```
GlobalData.objA.needMethod();
```

При этом у меня `GlobalData` - **singleton**.

---

Какие правильно поступать в данном случае? Какие шаблоны для этого используются? Или же, все таки я правильно все делаю?

*Вот примерная иллюстрация*
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Comment: что-то по описанию не совсем понятно зачем GlobalData нужен. Может быть какой-нибудь наглядный, но минимальный, пример кода? Возможно вместо GlobalData можно просто передавать в зависимый объект объект от которого он зависит при создании.

Comment: @Grundy GlobalData - для общей точки доступа. Вместо того, что бы делать статичными поля и методы объекта который должен быть использован.

Comment: А зачем было делать статичными поля и методы?

Comment: @Grundy Как зачем? У вас два родителя, А и B. Каким образом дочерний объект из родителя А узнает о существовании дочернего из родителя B? Только через статическую ссылку, а как иначе? Но тут, static мы даже не сможем использовать, потому что дочерние объекты будут не в единственном экземпляре.

Comment: А зачем ему вообще знать о дочернем из родителя В?

Comment: Можешь чуть больше задачу описать? Может быть тебе вообще нужно что-то другое? Кстати, по картинке и описанию смахивает на какую-то самопальную реализацию DI

Comment: @Grundy во первых, возможно ты не понял вопроса "это не про наследование, а про создание объектов". во вторых - как тут можно перейти в чат, что бы не переписоваться в комментариях? В вопросе же написано - "дети должны знать о друг друге"  Представь себе такую ситуацию, такое довольно часто возникает. <<Описывать, реальный пример не вижу смысла - на изображении наглядно видно - нижние объекты должны знать о верхних объектах, и работать с ними>>

Comment: @Grundy Извини, я просто реально не могу понять, что я не ясно описал в вопросе и в обсуждении.

Comment: Давайте [продолжим обсуждение в чате](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/87549/discussion-between-grundy-and-boneferz).

Comment: Скорее всего, это ошибка в проектировании архитектуры классов. Прямое нарушение принципа инкапсуляции. Без прояснения постановки задачи принять решение о правильности данной реализации весьма затруднительно. С моей точки зрения - это очень плохая реализация.

Comment: @АндрейТуманов Ошибка проектирования, плохая реализация, нарушение ооп принципов. Обоснуйте, пожалуйста, каждое заявление, иначе оно теряет каой либо смысл. Не забывайте - мы с вами на сайте, где делимся друг с другом полезной информацией. То есть по вашему хорошая реализация это когда во всем проекте один GOD класс, который манипулируют всеми созданными им дочерними объектами? Или как это понять? Дочерние объекты должны быть лишены какого либо функционала? Не понимаю, что вы имеете ввиду, под определением хорошей архитектуры

Comment: @АндрейТуманов вы абсолютно не правы. В данном вопросе идет речь об отношение между классами объектов в ООП, и этому есть определение https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Association_(object-oriented_programming) , а точнее это Агрегирование по ссылке

Comment: Видимо, абсолютно не прав. Вам виднее.